# How to avoid many nested loops

Tags: javascript, node.js

What would be ideal replacement for nested *for loops* in terms of performance and ease of reading code, if I have over 8 *for loops* (besides two for loops) where I'm forming two array lists that I use to conclude to only one *if statement* in order to produce a result.

The database has multiple rows like:

```
{
   id: 12345
   creator: "John"
   number: 2.5
   type: 1
}

{
   id: 45678
   creator: "Alex"
   number: 2.0
   type: 2
}
```

```
// create array of elements with type:1
chat.find({"type":1}).toArray(function(err, res){
   const array1_id = [];
   const array1_creator = [];
   const array1_number = [];
   
   // form array for each element
   for(a=0;a<res.length;a++){
      array1_id.push(res[a].id);
      array1_creator.push(res[a].creator);
      array1_number.push(res[a].number);
   }
   
   // create array of elements with type:2
   chat.find({"type":2}).toArray(function(err, res){
      const array2_id = [];
      const array2_creator = [];
      const array2_number = [];

      // form array for each element
      for(b=0;b<res.length;b++){
         array2_id.push(res[a].id);
         array2_creator.push(res[a].creator);
         array2_number.push(res[a].number);
      }

      outerloop: for(c=0;c<array1_id.length;c++){ // id (type: 1 row)

         var resNum1_id = array1_id[c];
         
         for(c1=0;c1<array1_creator.length;c1++){ // creator (type: 1 row)
            var resNum1_creator = array1_creator[c1];

            for(c2=0;c2<array1_number.length;c2++){ // number (type: 1 row)
               var resNum1_number = array1_number[c2];

               innerloop: for(d=0;d<array2_id.length;d++){ id (type: 2 row)
                  var resNum2_id = array2_id[d];

                  for(d1=0;d1<array2_creator.length;d1++){ creator (type: 2 row)
                     var resNum2_creator = array2_creator[d1];

                     for(d2=0;d2<array2_number.length;d2++){ // number (type: 2 row)
                        var resNum2_number = array2_number[d2];

                        // find rows where condition is true
                        if(resNum1_number>=resNum2_number){
                           console.log
                             resNum1_id+
                             resNum1_creator+
                             resNum1_number+
                             "\n"+
                             resNum2_id+
                             resNum2_creator+
                             resNum2_number+                             
                           );
                           break outerloop;
                        }
                        
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         } 
      }

   });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use two loops to loop over the two result arrays, comparing the `num` values from each.

```js
// create array of elements with type:1 
chat.find({
    "type": 1
  })
  .toArray(function(err, res1) {
    // create array of elements with type:2
    chat.find({
        "type": 2
      })
      .toArray(function(err, res2) {
        for (let i = 0; i < res1.length; i++) {
          for (let j = 0; j < res2.length; j++) {
            if (res1[i].num >= res2[j].num) {
              console.log(res1[i].id + res1[i].creator + res1[i].num + "\n" + res2[i].id + res2[i].creator + res2[i].num);
              return;
            }
          }
        }
      });
  });
```